# Rough edges when converting PNG file to PDF with ImageMagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, png

I'm converting PNG files to PDF using `ImageMagick` and it works great but I'm having a small issue with some images like this:

[image]

When converting it with `convert fanta-logo.png out.pdf` the resulting PDF file looks like this:

[image]

There are rough edges on the corners of the image which are not present on the original PNG file. I tried converting PNG to TIFF or JPEG 2000 and then to PDF but the result is the same. Even using Inkscape to convert the PNG file to PDF produces the same result so I'm guessing this is something related to the specific PNG file or to PDF.

Has anyone experienced this? The output from `identify` is the following:

`fanta-logo.png PNG 611x600 611x600+0+0 8-bit sRGB 215227B 0.000u 0:00.000`

I'm using IM 7.0.8-64 Q16 on Windows 10 x64. I extracted the alpha channel of the PNG file using `convert fanta-logo.png -alpha extract alpha.png` and it looks clean:

[image]

Comment: Try converting to JPG and see if you get the same thing.

Comment: Try extracting the alpha channel to a separate file to see if the edges are woolly... `convert fanta-logo.png -alpha extract alpha.png`.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me on IM 6.9.11.23 Q16 Mac OSX with libpng 1.6.37.

```
convert fanta.png fanta.pdf
```

[fanta.pdf](https://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/fanta.pdf)

What is your IM version and your version of libpng?  Perhaps you need to upgrade one or both.

Comment: I'm using IM 7.0.8-64 Q16 on Windows 10 x64

Comment: That version of ImageMagick is rather old. It is now at 7.0.10.23. So I suggest you upgrade. Also you did not answer my question about what version of libpng. Perhaps that is old or buggy version. `magick -list format` and look at the end of the line for PNG. That will tell you your version.

Comment: I will upgrade IM and test again! The libpng version is also 1.6.37!